# Changing client credentials in Keycloak identity provider prevents users from loggin in

Tags: keycloak

We're running Keycloak (v20.0.0) with an identity provider connecting to an Azure Active Directory which works fine.

Now we need to update the client credentials (client id/secret) as we're changing the web app registration within Azure AD. After saving the new credentials in the Keycloak identity provider, users that could previously log in now get an alert 'Account already exists' which is weird in the first place. I'd expect KC to handle the client change gracefully as it is still the same identity provider. However, now it gives me the option 'Add to existing account' which sends an email to the user with a confirmation link. Clicking that link results in an error.

DB error log:

```
2023-03-17 08:48:01.750 UTC [69] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "constraint_40"
2023-03-17 08:48:01.750 UTC [69] DETAIL:  Key (identity_provider, user_id)=(azure-ad-oidc, 20779c27-7d7b-48f0-9254-f94cd15a2291) already exists.
2023-03-17 08:48:01.750 UTC [69] STATEMENT:  insert into FEDERATED_IDENTITY (REALM_ID, TOKEN, FEDERATED_USER_ID, FEDERATED_USERNAME, IDENTITY_PROVIDER, USER_ID) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
```

Keycloak error log:

```
2023-03-17 08:48:01,750 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (executor-thread-28) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
2023-03-17 08:48:01,751 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (executor-thread-28) ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "constraint_40"
  Detail: Key (identity_provider, user_id)=(azure-ad-oidc, 20779c27-7d7b-48f0-9254-f94cd15a2291) already exists.
2023-03-17 08:48:01,752 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] (executor-thread-28) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2023-03-17 08:48:01,754 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.resources.IdentityBrokerService] (executor-thread-28) identityProviderUnexpectedErrorMessage: org.keycloak.models.ModelDuplicateException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.PersistenceExceptionConverter.convert(PersistenceExceptionConverter.java:80)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.PersistenceExceptionConverter.invoke(PersistenceExceptionConverter.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaUserProvider.addFederatedIdentity(JpaUserProvider.java:170)
    at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.addFederatedIdentity(UserStorageManager.java:543)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.addFederatedIdentity(UserCacheSession.java:802)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.IdentityBrokerService.afterFirstBrokerLogin(IdentityBrokerService.java:700)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.IdentityBrokerService.afterFirstBrokerLogin(IdentityBrokerService.java:653)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:192)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:141)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:32)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:151)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:42)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.next(RoutingContextWrapper.java:200)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:71)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.next(RoutingContextWrapper.java:200)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$6.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:430)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$6.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:408)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.next(RoutingContextWrapper.java:200)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.integration.web.QuarkusRequestFilter.lambda$createBlockingHandler$0(QuarkusRequestFilter.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:564)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1411)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1394)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor209.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.PersistenceExceptionConverter.invoke(PersistenceExceptionConverter.java:60)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3375)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3908)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "constraint_40"
  Detail: Key (identity_provider, user_id)=(azure-ad-oidc, 20779c27-7d7b-48f0-9254-f94cd15a2291) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:152)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor197.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.postgresql.ds.PGPooledConnection$StatementHandler.invoke(PGPooledConnection.java:441)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 69 more
```

From the logs it's pretty obvious what's going wrong but I don't understand why. Is it not possible to change the client credentials of an identity provider? Then KC should make this a read-only thing.